# deactivation hook is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a plugin in wordpress which have a database table, Upon deactivation I want to delete that table also but it is not working with following code, deactivation is successful but table was not dropped.
here is my class function and hook:

```
public function deact() {
        global $wpdb;
        delete_option('ACP_settings');
        delete_option('ACP_advance_settings');
        $q = "DROP TABLE tb_name";
        $wpdb->query($q);
    }

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deact');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much work, I have got it worked. The main problem is class, When I have declared that as function not as class method its worked.

I updating it for other users

Comment: If you want to use a class method, use something like `register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array('Plugin_Class_Name', 'deact'))`. (You'd normally declare the `deact()` method as static. There's a [thorough example of the different approaches between using a standalone function and a class method here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979).